# Query a date in AWS DynamoDB that matches exact date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The DynamoDB I have has the following date in the created field: Mon Nov 07 2016 09:24:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)

I have the following parameters for my query but I cannot get the date to match exactly either:

```
var params =
{
    TableName: 'Users', 
    KeyConditionExpression: 'email = :email',
    FilterExpression: 'created = :created',
    ExpressionAttributeValues:
    {
        ':email': email,
        ':created': '2016-11-07 09:24:35'
    }
};
```

How do I get the query to match the exact date?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't have any native data-type for date/time. In other words, it doesn't 'understand' date/time on its own.

So, what you want isn't directly supported. You have two options:

- Store date as Number, and Query accordingly.
- Store date as String, as you are doing now. And while querying, convert input to the format that is stored in DynamoDB, so that the two match exactly.